# Missing required parameter client_id when using amplify for google authentication

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, federated-identity

I'm trying to setup Google Sign-in using Amplify on AWS.

After running the CLI tools, an `aws-exports.js` file was created.
The content of the file looks as follows. (I blurred some of the id's for security reasons)

[image: aws-exports.js]

And I've added a button to the html of my component:

```
<amplify-google-button></amplify-google-button>
```

There does indeed show a sign-in button for google.

[image: Google sign in button]

However, when I click the button, an error shows in the console log.

```
Dw {message: "Missing required parameter 'client_id'", KK: true, stack: "gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Missing require…ask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10872:18)"}
KK: true
message: "Missing required parameter 'client_id'"
stack: "gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Missing required parameter 'client_id'↵    at new Dw (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.nl.r1otz6eix_k.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQE/rs=AGLTcCOGfNNm-txjpYHjoYjEhq8W5zaIHw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:555:25)↵    at ox (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.nl.r1otz6eix_k.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQE/rs=AGLTcCOGfNNm-txjpYHjoYjEhq8W5zaIHw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:574:131)↵    at Object._.Lx [as init] (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.nl.r1otz6eix_k.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQE/rs=AGLTcCOGfNNm-txjpYHjoYjEhq8W5zaIHw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:592:269)↵    at AmplifyGoogleButton.getAuthInstance (http://localhost:4200/13.js:278:38)↵    at AmplifyGoogleButton.signInWithGoogle (http://localhost:4200/13.js:288:14)↵    at HTMLElement.onClick (http://localhost:4200/13.js:294:129)↵    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9650:35)↵    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9418:51)↵    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9731:38)↵    at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10872:18)"
__proto__: _.Tc
```

Before I created all this, I created a client ID on the Google Cloud Platform.

[image: Google Cloud Platform ID]

The Amplify configuration page has an app which is called "ZBaduk", with an environment called "dev". This page is linked to cognito in authentication:

[image: Amplify linked to Cognito]

This ID effectively matches to the ID of the AWS User Pool, which has the configuration of the Google Identity.

[image: User Pool ID]

So, is there some other place where I need to enter the google client ID perhaps ?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a client-id property on the `amplify-google-button` element.

```
<amplify-google-button clientId="87153937946-md7....apps.googleusercontent.com"></amplify-google-button>
```

Comment: I'm honestly not sure that's all of it. 
After more trouble later on, I decided to abandon amplify and setup all of this manually.